# Read a .txt file using batch and extract a string between ()

Tags: file, batch-file, token, cut, between

I have a .LOG file whitch contains:

```
2015-01-20 17:00:59 (15.6 MB/s) - `c:/temp/teste_velocidade.tar.gz' saved [253311/253311]
```

I'd like to extract the content between "(" ")" into a variable.

Ex.:

```
$number=15.6
$unit=MB
```

How can I do This?

I'm seaching for a solution for it but batch is not familiar to me.

Comment: Shouldn't the unit be `MB/s`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this :

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=3,4 Delims=() " %%a in (test.log) do (
  set "$Number=%%a" 
  set "$Unit=%%b"
)

echo Number : [%$Number%]
echo Unit   : [%$Unit%]
```

I Used here a file named `test.log` for the test